# MIPS or ARM board with 2+ network interfaces

Tags: motherboard, network-adapter, development-board

I am looking for a single board computer (like raspberry or odroid) with 2+ ethernet ports, on board.

Either MIPS or ARM is ok, and should be able to run linux.

Any recommendation is appreciated.

P.S, usb network adapters can't be used to increase network interfaces.

Comment: A lot of these devices use USB 'internally' for additional ports, would that be ok? Also, do you need gigabit or is fast ethernet ok?

Comment: Usb based nic aren't good, but fast Ethernet is ok.